# how do I find one element in a list collection?

Tags: java

The for loop alters around the ArrayList and add the elements now we try to find element but come seem to get it right.

```
   List<savingsAccount> listSavA = new ArrayList<>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String name = 
        savingsAccount sA = new savingsAccount(i, name);
        listSavA.add(sA);
    }
   
    boolean find;
    if (find = listSavA.contains("Smith")){
        System.out.println("The value is not found");
    }else {
        System.out.println("The element smith is found");
    }
    assertEquals(false, find);
```

Comment: You loop through the list and call `getName()` so you can compare correctly.

Comment: `listSavA` is a `List<savingsAccount>`. You call `contains(...)` on it with a `String` as argument. There are no `String`s in that list.

Answer (score 0):

loop through the list to find the match

```
boolean find = false;

for(savingsAccount s : listSavA) {
    if(s.getName().equals("Smith")) {
       find = true;
       System.out.println("The element smith is found");
       break;
  }
}

if(!find) {
   System.out.println("The value is not found");
}
```

Above is the for each loop which will look for "name" member of every element in the list. It will check for equality of name with Smith and breaks the loop once it finds Smith, assigning true to the value of find and printing the element Smith is found. In the end if the find is still false it will print out the value is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find some element while iterating the list of 'listSavingAccount' , you can do so by doing -

```
List<SavingsAccount> listSavA = new ArrayList<>();

    for (SavingsAccount account : listSavingAccount) {
        boolean find;
        if (find = listSavA.contains("Smith")) {
            listSavA.add(account);
            System.out.println("The value is not found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The element smith is found");
        }

    }
```

if the string is found in the list (listSavingAccount), you can add that to new list which you are creating here.

Answer (score 0):

The list contains full of objects, so there is no meaning to search with string value.  Please refer below code this might help you.

```
boolean find= listSavA.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getName().equals("Smith"));
```

Comment: "*The list contains full of objects ...*" - Yes, but specific `Object`s (`savingsAccount`s). --- "*... so there is meaning to search with string value.*" - I do not understand what you are trying to say with this sentence.

Comment: sorry, i about to say "there is no meaning" to search directly with string value, so java 8 has streaming functions to solve this search.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `contains()` expects a `savingsAccount`, but you provide a `String`.

You can do:

```
boolean containsSmith = listSavA.stream()
        .anyMatch(sa -> sa.getName().equals("Smith"));

if (containsSmith){
    System.out.println("The value is not found");
}else {
    System.out.println("The element smith is found");
}
```